# Flutter Firestore offline persistent

Tags: dart, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I want to use offline firestore persistent, but I don't get the right code. On the kotlin tutorial said like this :

```
db.collection("members").document()
    .addSnapshotListener(object : EventListener<DocumentSnapshot> {
        override fun onEvent(snapshot: DocumentSnapshot?,
                            e: FirebaseFirestoreException?) {
            if (e != null) {
                Log.w(ContentValues.TAG, "Listen error", e)
                err_msg.text = e.message
                err_msg.visibility = View.VISIBLE;
                return
            }
            snapshot?.reference?.set(data)
            val intent = Intent()
            setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent)
            this@FormActivity.finish()
        }
    }
)
```

I try to use this code on flutter :

```
Firestore.instance.collection("hega").document().setData(data);
```

And also try this :

```
Firestore.instance.collection("hega").add(data);
```

Both works if online but not working when device is offline (using airplane mode)

**UPDATE:**
So above code are actually works offline.

```
Firestore.instance.collection("hega").document().setData(data);
```

I just need to setup stream listener to the document snapshot, to see that the data is added to the local cache. But the other problem is when the device comes online, the offline data is not synced to server.

Comment: Are you using kotlin code in Flutter?

Comment: Nope, I just found a tutorial how to use firestore offline on kotlin. And i want to use it on flutter dart.

Comment: did you find any solution when the device comes online?

Comment: Hi @rickdroio nothing todo, all already handled by the sdk.

Comment: How did you solve this with flutter ? can you please write your code of how to make sure document is completed writing to cache ?

Answer (score 3):

You can enable offline data persistence like so as mentioned in the [flutterfire docs](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/#access-data-offline).

For web

```dart
await FirebaseFirestore.instance.enablePersistence();
```

For other platforms

```dart
FirebaseFirestore.instance.settings = Settings(persistenceEnabled: false);
```